# Two DataGrids one DataSet how to set the realation (many to many)?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm, datagrid

I'm having some problems here about showing the ralation of two datatables in a dataset which have a many to many relation. And each datatable is bound to one Datagrid.

So I have designed in VS 2015 DataSet Designer my file database so there is one datatable Material and one datatable Technik and also on for the many to many relation. If I start my app I do an connection to my database an fill my dataset with the tables - this all happens in viewmodel...

```
    private void InitDataSet()
    {
        if (File.Exists(dbFilepath))
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string query = "";

                connection.Open();

                systemTime = DateTime.Now;

                query = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Materialliste";
                dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);

                dataAdapter.Fill(MlDb.Tbl_Materialliste);

                query = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Technik";
                dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);
                dataAdapter.Fill(MlDb.Tbl_Technik);
                //dataAdapter.Fill(MlDb.Temp_Technik);

                query = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Besitzt";
                dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);
                dataAdapter.Fill(MlDb.Tbl_Besitzt);
           }

                MlDataSetCollection.Add(MlDb);

                // hier muss noch die Tabelle "Log" hinzugefuegt werden
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Pfad oder Datei existiert nicht
        }
    }
```

MlDb is the object created from the designer and is an extended dataset...

so and my XAML looks like this:

```
           <DataGrid x:Name="MaterialDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MlDb.Tbl_Materialliste, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                                <ic:CallMethodAction MethodName="RowEditEnding" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <ic:CallMethodAction MethodName="SelectionChanged" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Material" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=MaterialID}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Materialkurztext" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Materialkurztext}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Herstellername" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Herstellername}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Her.-Artikelnummer" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Her.-Artikelnummer}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dokument" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Dokument}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subst.-Material" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Subst.-Material}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="26,1,-25,-1">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="TechnikDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MlDb.Temp_Technik}" Margin="0,0,34,0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Header="Auswahl" Width="70" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Technik ID" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=TechnikID}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Techniktyp" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Techniktyp}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anlage" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Anlage}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anlagengruppe" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Anlagengruppe}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bemerkung" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Bemerkung}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

So the parent table is Material and Child is Technik - how can I select one Material in the datagrid which follows with a complete Technik Table lsit in the other DataGrid an shows relations with a checkbox. Checkbox selected means Material hat Technik and unselected no relation.

I really need some help here guys - if you have other recommendations let me know! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could break down MlDb object into 2 ObservableCollection and have the second collection update its items according to first DataGrid's selected item.

Your DataGrids should bind their ItemsSource to those properties holding the collections.

Comment: And how shall that article help? Maybe I'm a newbie but I know mvvm and I know what OCs can do... But the point is that I dont know how your approach shall helpme to solve the problem I'm facing...

The relation thing of this is done in datagrid and itemssource of DG1 is datatable1 and of DG2 itemssource is datatable2...

maybe u can show some code that I maybe get your approach